# iText7 SetJustification(2) works partially

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I have a code which takes a PDF template, inserts some input values into the template and creates an output PDF file.
One of the fields in the PDF file is a free text which can include a value with Hebrew/English/Numbers or signs characters.
I'm using the following code to make the text readable in Hebrew with RTL display:

```
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader reader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(pdfTemplatePath); //src);
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter writer = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(pdfOutPutFile); //dest);
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(reader, writer);
iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm form = iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

IDictionary<String, iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

// iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont = iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(iText.IO.Font.FontProgram
FontProgramFactory.RegisterFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\ARIALUNI.TTF", "arialUnicode");
iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont myFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("arialUnicode", iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);

pdf.GetFirstPage().GetResources().AddFont(pdf, myFont);

// Set Field value by Fields mapping
foreach (string fieldName in formFieldMap.Keys)
{
    fields[fieldName].SetValue(formFieldMap[fieldName].ToString());
    fields[fieldName].SetFont(myFont);

    // displaying the text: 0 Left-justified 1 Centered 2 Right-justified
    **fields[fieldName].SetJustification(2);**
}
```

My problem is that the text is not aligned to right.

Field with text-align left:

[image: Field with text-align left]

What more can I do to set the text-align on the right?

Comment: What happens if you SetJustification(**0**) ?

Comment: When I SetJustification(0) - nothing happens, it's just the same.

Comment: To display RTL content correctly you need a bidi algorithm. It is implemented in `pdfCalligraph` add-on for iText7. Are you using this add-on? If you are, then either you are a paid customer or you have a trial license. In both cases you'd better address an iText representative with your problem. If you are not using `pdfCalligraph`, then you should, because otherwise the result will most likely be incorrect. It is not possible to achieve desired output with mix of RTL and LTR text with iText7 Community edition.

Comment: I have deleted my answer, because @AlexeySubach's answer is more authorative than mine. As it turns out, you need the pdfCalligraph add-on to achieve this.

Comment: I have already installed the itext7.pdfcalligraph.1.0.3.

Comment: This might be a viewer issue, with the viewer not taking the quadding (Q) entry of the dictionary into account. Have you tried opening the pdf in different viewers to see if there's a difference?

Comment: Thanks Samuel, All the other fields are aligned to the right, except this one which I'm struggling with. So I do not think it's the viewer's fault.
But I would like to know what other viewers do you refer to?
I just double click the file and it opens in the browser.